# Equivalent definition of Wiener capacity

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, harmonic-functions, potential-theory

Fix $n\ge3$. Let $F$ be a compact susbset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.
There are two definitions of Wiener capacity.

One is 
$$
\mathrm{cap}\left(F\right)=\inf\left\{ \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\left|\nabla u\right|^{2}dx:u\in C_{0}^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right),u\mid_{F}=1\right\} .
$$
The other is 
$$
\mathrm{cap}\left(F\right)=\sup\left\{ \mu\left(F\right):\int_{F}\mathcal{E}\left(x-y\right)d\mu\left(y\right)\le1\quad\text{on }\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus F\right\} ,
$$
where the supremum is taken over all positive finite Radon measures
$\mu$ on $F$ and $\mathcal{E}$ is the fundamental solution of $-\triangle$
in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, i.e., 
$$
\mathcal{E}\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\left(n-2\right)\omega_{n}}\left|x\right|^{2-n},
$$
where $\omega_{n}$ is the area of the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

According to author, two definitions are equivalent. But I cannot
find any kind of proof.

The paper I read is V. Maz'ya and M. Shubin, *Discreteness of
spectrum and positivity criteria for Schrödinger operators*, Ann.
of Math. **162** (2005) 919-942.

Comment: From my understanding, this is a standard result in potential theory. You might find some material in Adams & Hedberg: "Function spaces and potential theory".